# Term for Market Expansion (growing the Entire Market Size) via Signifincant Price Reduction

Tags: business-language

I am looking for the business term for market expansion (growing the entire market size) via significant price reduction.

For example, ~20 years ago, enterprise grade CRM used to be exclusively in the purview of large corporations, costing in the tens to hundreds-of-thousands of dollars, due to bespoke implementations (the only option).  Then, Saleforce.com came in with (arguably) the first SaaS software CRM solution and expanded the market by making it significantly more affordable for the average small business, in the hundreds of dollars range.

Another example might be Commodore Computers, know for the mantra "Computers for the Masses, Not the Classes" who entered the home computer market with a competitive home computer at a significantly lower price point, making a home computer more affordable at a price in reach for a much larger audience, thus massively expanding the potential customer base and opening the market up to a whole new set of consumers.

"Democratization" and "commoditization" are close concepts, but not quite the term I am looking for.

Thank you.

Comment: Technically speaking, changing price does not change the market size it only changes the market equilibrium quantity supplied and quantity demanded.

Comment: But there can be a shift in supply through innovation.

Comment: It’s a business strategy. An early example is Henry Ford’s Model T for “the great multitude”—foreseeing a market that doesn’t yet exist.

Comment: Yes, this is more like creating a new market by radical price change.  Usually due to some sort of technology innovation.  As @xanne said, Ford’s assembly line great example too.